# embedded video in asp:ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a `Link` field. The sample value of `Link` like this : `https://vimeo.com/62941191`

I want to bind `Link` in `asp:ListView` and show video inside it. Don't know how to show video. Can somebody tell me?

Answer (score 0):

Use link button and set your url in linkbutton  postbackurl property